# Object reference is required + resx-file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

i have a problem internationalizing my code. It pretty much works great everywhere on my site, except in this part of code.

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(strings), Name = "BevestigWachtwoord")]
    private CultureInfo resourceCulture;
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = ResourceManager.GetString("PassMismatch",resourceCulture))]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

the error(Object reference is required.........) is at ResourceManager.GetString("PassMismatch",resourceCulture))]
I get the same error if i try ErrorMessage=strings.PassMismatch (where strings is my resourse file)
when i just fill in a string, it does work.
i had the same problem  for display, but i fixed that by doing

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof(strings), Name = "Email")]
```

Is there something similar i can try here?

EDIT : My Errors

Error   13  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MvcApplication2.Models.RegisterModel.resourceCulture'    C:\Users\stuart\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Models\AccountModels.cs   74  86  MvcApplication2
Error   14  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(string, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)'    C:\Users\stuart\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Models\AccountModels.cs   74  45  MvcApplication2
Error   11  The expression being assigned to 'MvcApplication2.Models.RegisterModel.error' must be constant  C:\Users\stuart\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Models\AccountModels.cs   67  30  MvcApplication2
Error   12  The property or indexer 'MvcApplication2.strings.PassMismatch' cannot be used in this context because it lacks the get accessor C:\Users\stuart\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Models\AccountModels.cs   67  30  MvcApplication2

for the other comment, i'm trying stuff like 
    ErrorMessage = resourceCulture     ResourceManager.GetString("PassMismatch",Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture))]

but just nothing is working

Comment: Do you (and if so, how) assign resourceCulture before you pass it to ResourceManager.GetString()...? Otherwise you will pass null!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace you get with the exception?

Comment: i dont think it is null, since my other localization in the Display part works, even if it is null, how do i get the currentCulture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = ResourceManager.GetString("PassMismatch",resourceCulture))]
```

With this line:

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PassMismatch")]
```

And make sure you've added your PassMismatch string to the resource file that is mapped to your `strings` resource type.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you try to pass a static reference for the ResourceManager and get the CurrentCulture:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Resources;
using System.Globalization;

namespace QMVC.ViewModel.Home
{
  public class TResViewModel
  {
    private static ResourceManager r = QMVC.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = r.GetString("Test", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture))]
    public string Test { get; set; }
  }
}
```

You will have an error at the compile- time:
*"An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"*

In other terms: you can't set dynamically a value to an argument of an attribute because  an attribute parameter must be resolved at compile time (It makes sense).

The best (simple) way is probably to use the others arguments for a Validation Attribute, ErrorMessageResourceType and ErrorMessageResourceName:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Resources;
using System.Globalization;

namespace QMVC.ViewModel.Home
{
  public class TResViewModel
  {  
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(QMVC.Properties.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Test")]
    public string Test2 { get; set; }

      }
    }
```

The ErrorMessage will be create with the type of your Resource, the given key and the CurrentCulture, during the Validation process.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, im not sure how to implement this in my code. I have tried insteat of the Compare line

[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PassMisMatch")]
i don't seem to get an error now, i can register now even if passwords dont match, so it isnt comparing anymore.

Comment: Still use Compare on ConfirmPassword. Use Required only on Password.